# what is does format("%s-%s",) mean in terraform?

Tags: terraform

I am looking through some terraform code and not sure what the format("%s-%s",) does below?

app_resourcegroup_name = format(**"%s-%s**", module.env_vars.resourcegroup_prefix, "app")

Comment: https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a common format string as you might find it in c, bash, or go for that matter.

In your example, `%s` means this should be substituted for a string. The string values are supplied by the additional arguments  `module.env_vars.resourcegroup_prefix` and `"app"`.

In your example `%s-%s`, assuming the prefix is "foo", the final result would be `foo-app`.

You can see more information about format strings here: https://pkg.go.dev/fmt and here https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/format. Terraform is written in go, but its format string syntax can differ slightly.

Comment: Is `format("%s", var.function_name)` likely to have the same result as `var.function_name`? In other words, is `format` redundant here in this context `tags = merge(local.tags.map, { Function = format("%s", var.function_name) } )`

Comment: @NeilG, its appears to be redundant, yes.